# Postgres data base need suggestion creating an index for table

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, postgresql-performance

I a have a table structure as below. For fetching the data from table I am having search criteria as mentioned below. I am writing a singe sql query as per requirement(sample query I mentioned below).  I need to create an index for the table to cover all the search criteria. It will be helpful somebody advice me.

Table structure(columns):

1. applicationid varchar(15),
2. trans_tms timestamp,
3. SSN varchar,
4. firstname varchar,
5. lastname  varchar,
6. DOB     date,
7. Zipcode  smallint,
8. adddetais  json

Search criteria will be from API will be fall under 4 categories. All 4 categories are mandatory. At any cost I will receive 4 categories of values for against single applicant.

Search criteria:

1. ssn&last name (last name need to use function I.e. soundex(lastname)=soundex('inputvalue').
2. ssn & DOB
3. ssn&zipcode
4. firstname&lastname&DOB.

Query:

I am trying to write.
Sample query is:

```
Select * 
from table 
where ((ssn='aaa' and soundex(lastname)=soundex('xxx') 
       or ((ssn='aaa' and dob=xxx) 
       or (ssn='aaa' and zipcode = 'xxx') 
       or (firstname='xxx' and lastname='xxx' and dob= xxxx));
```

For considering performance I need to create an index for the table. Might be composite. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Please provide proper information for performance questions. Consider instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 0):

Some Approaches I would follow:

1. Yes, you are correct composite index/multicolumn index will give benefit in AND conditions of two columns, however, indexes would overlap on columns for given conditions.
   Documentation : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-multicolumn.html
2. You can use a UNION instead of OR.

Reference : https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/

3. If multiple conditions could be combined for e.g: ssn should be 'aaa' with any combination, then modifying the where clause with lesser OR is preferable.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh for response. considering above fields and I mentioned all 4 categories are mandate. I am thinking to go with composite index like below. 
if prior that anything needs to be taken into account. any impact based on this. I am new to Postgres too.            
  CREATE INDEX test_dupapp_1 ON DUPAPPCHECK using btree (ssn,soundex(lastname));
  CREATE INDEX test_dupapp_2 ON DUPAPPCHECK using btree (ssn,dob);
  CREATE INDEX test_dupapp_3 ON DUPAPPCHECK using btree (ssn,zipcode);
  CREATE INDEX test_dupapp_4 ON DUPAPPCHECK using btree (upper(lastname),upper(firstname),dob);